# Rufus doesn't start

Tags: media, usb-drive

I downloaded the Rufus utility to create a bootable USB. However, when I try to run it, it just pops up a message box "One or more arguments are invalid" and doesn't start. I tried the version 3.5 and 3.6 and for download used MS Edge and Firefox - all without success.

I am running Windows 10.

I couldn't find anything related on the Internet. Any suggestions what to do?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing..

Answer (score 2):

Unplug any [USB devices](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/issues/845). It worked for me after I unplugged a USB Flash Drive. Weird!